# Create list of objects with generated key value in Kotlin

Tags: list, kotlin

New in Kotlin;
I need to get a list of HeightModel class objects from the function

```
class HeightModel(id: Int, height: Int)
```

I am using below code. but getting an empty list

```
var i = 1
var j = 145
val li = emptyList<HeightModel>()
while(i < 46 && j < 191){
    li.toMutableList().add(HeightModel(i, j))
    i ++
    j ++
 }
return li
```

I am getting an emptylist instead. My expected result shall be

```
listOf(HeightModel(1, 145), HeightModel(2, 146) .....HeightModel(46, 190))
```

Help is generously appreciated

Comment: this can be done in one line `return (1..46).map { HeightModel(it, it + 144) }`, add `.toMutableList()` if the function returns `MutableList`

Comment: @IR42, thanks fro help and advice

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The probles is that `li.toMutableList()` returns **new instance** of list and, thus `li` is still empty list.

Actually `emptyList()` will returns immutable empty list.
So the solutions actually is next:

```kotlin
var i = 1
var j = 145
val li = mutableListOf<HeightModel>()
while(i < 46 && j < 191){
    li.add(HeightModel(i, j))
    i ++
    j ++
 }
return li
```

or just `val li = ArrayList<HeightModel>()`

Answer (score 2):

This is a more idiomatic Kotlin to achieve what you want:

```
data class HeightModel(val id: Int, val height: Int)

fun main() {
    val ids = 1..45
    val heights = 145..190
    val heightModelList = (ids zip heights).map { HeightModel(it.first, it.second) }
}
```

If you would like to know more about the features used in this code, please read about *Data Classes*, *Ranges and Progressions* and *zip* function in Kotlin. If you want to code in Kotlin, it is useful to learn a more functional way of handling data as I did with the *map* function above.